# Include GeoIP.dat into the ClickOnce Deployment

Tags: c#, include, clickonce, geoip

I created a C# application, that depends on the MaxMind GeoIP.dat file to work.

How can I include it into the ClickOnce build so the GeoIP.dat file gets automatically installed into the application directory?

I added the GeoIP.dat as a resource but that didn't help, it doesn't get included.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not". Also, Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself,

you need to go to the resource properties and set the resource to be always included, then you can embed them into the build process and it is included.